# Типы данных sqlite. Почему не могу записать длинное число

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

Создаю базу

```
 Database.execSQL("create table myTable ("
                    + "date int,"
                    + "json text" + ");");
```

Почему я могу вместо `int`  написать `long` и база данных создается? Правда диапазон int остается.

Проблема в том что UnixTime  число вот такой длины получается `1513746000000`.

`long` при записи в таблицу, как я знаю, преобразуется в `int`. и у меня получается  `1917511808` . Но в [документации](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html) написано, что integer в зависимости от длины числа может достигать до 8 байтов. Так почему моё число уменьшается, если int, под который выделено 8 байт, может в себе его поместить?  
 Мне теперь что, делить число на 1000 чтобы в секунды преобразовать, сохранять, а после снова умножать на 1000 для того чтобы в дату парсить?

**UPD** 
 в этом коде: вместо типов данных можно написать любое слово. Удаляю приложение с телефона. Устанавливаю заново и всё работает, чтобы я не написал. Даже Wipe Date делаю на эмуляторе перед тем как начать установку приложения
`Database.execSQL("create table myTable ("
                    + "date int,"
                    + "json text" + ");");`

Например код из урока на [стартандроид](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/74-urok-34-hranenie-dannyh-sqlite.html)

```
 `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnClickListener {

    final String LOG_TAG = "myLogs";

    Button btnAdd, btnRead, btnClear;
    EditText etName, etEmail;

    DBHelper dbHelper;

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btnAdd.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnRead = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRead);
        btnRead.setOnClickListener(this);

        btnClear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnClear);
        btnClear.setOnClickListener(this);

        etName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etName);
        etEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etEmail);

        // создаем объект для создания и управления версиями БД
        dbHelper = new DBHelper(this);
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        // создаем объект для данных
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

        // получаем данные из полей ввода
        String name = etName.getText().toString();
        String email = etEmail.getText().toString();

        // подключаемся к БД
        SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();


        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Insert in mytable: ---");
                // подготовим данные для вставки в виде пар: наименование столбца - значение

                cv.put("name", name);
                cv.put("email", email);
                // вставляем запись и получаем ее ID
                long rowID = db.insert("mytable", null, cv);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "row inserted, ID = " + rowID);
                break;
            case R.id.btnRead:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Rows in mytable: ---");
                // делаем запрос всех данных из таблицы mytable, получаем Cursor
                Cursor c = db.query("mytable", null, null, null, null, null, null);

                // ставим позицию курсора на первую строку выборки
                // если в выборке нет строк, вернется false
                if (c.moveToFirst()) {

                    // определяем номера столбцов по имени в выборке
                    int idColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("id");
                    int nameColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("name");
                    int emailColIndex = c.getColumnIndex("email");

                    do {
                        // получаем значения по номерам столбцов и пишем все в лог
                        Log.d(LOG_TAG,
                                "ID = " + c.getInt(idColIndex) +
                                        ", name = " + c.getString(nameColIndex) +
                                        ", email = " + c.getString(emailColIndex));
                        // переход на следующую строку
                        // а если следующей нет (текущая - последняя), то false - выходим из цикла
                    } while (c.moveToNext());
                } else
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "0 rows");
                c.close();
                break;
            case R.id.btnClear:
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- Clear mytable: ---");
                // удаляем все записи
                int clearCount = db.delete("mytable", null, null);
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "deleted rows count = " + clearCount);
                break;
        }
        // закрываем подключение к БД
        dbHelper.close();
    }


    class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            // конструктор суперкласса
            super(context, "myDB", null, 1);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "--- onCreate database ---");
            // создаем таблицу с полями
            db.execSQL("create table mytable ("
                    + "id integer primary key autoincrement,"
                    + "name wqerw,"
                    + "email text" + ");");
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        }
    }

}`
```

Всё работает. Но как видите в классе DBHelper при создании таблицы столбец name содержит фигню. И туда можно написать что угодно и всё продолжает работать...

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71016/discussion-on-question-by-turalllb---sqlite-----).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вычитал вот такое: Отмечу, что в инструкции создания таблицы для каждого поля мы задали тип данных для его значений, этот тип данных игнорируется программой `"SQLite"`. Система управления базой данных "`SQLite`" довольно свободно относится к определению типов данных, что не характерно для стандарта языка `SQL`. Типизация данных в `"SQLite"` основывается на так называемом принципе `"typeless"`, означающий игнорирование информации о типе данных в определении столбцов таблицы при ее создании с помощью инструкции `CREATE TABLE`. И все же лучше включать имена типов столбцов при объявлении таблиц, это повысит переносимость вашей базы данных.

Теперь понятно, почему я могу написать там вместо типа что угодно и таблица всё равно создается. 
 Была проблема: точно так же как в коде, приложенном к вопросу(с стартандроид) я записываю `ContentValues`  в котором число типа long, а в лог я выводил эту запись из таблицы таким образом:

```
Log.d(LOG_TAG, "date = " + c.getInt(idDate));
```

Т.е. на выходе из таблицы, я сам же и приводил запись к int.

Решение:  `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "date = " + c.getLong(idDate));`

Comment: Естественно. Это же уже Java-обертка над БД, а Java как известно язык со строгой типизацией. То есть БД отдает 8-байтный INTEGER, а Java уже режет его до своего `int` при использовании `getInt()`

Comment: вобще,вы же сохраняли в бд тип long, с чего вы взяли, что извлекая int получите то же число, это территория Java, с ней такие штуки не проходят и хранение в бд тут никаким образом не влияет

Comment: Дело в том, что я сделал копипаст,  я не посмотрел на часть кода,которая извлекает,  а уперся в начало, где я создаю таблицу и не мог понять почему задав вместо типа данных хоть йероглифы моя таблица создавалась. Позже поняв что в sqlite это игнорируется, пошел читать код дальше.  В общем затупил